# How can I replace default boost with my compiled boost in Linux?

Tags: linux, boost

I compile a boost library. I set the prefix '/home/lixiang/local'. And I want to compile some C++ application using my compiled boost library. But the compiling process also invokes the default boost in Linux.
How can I replace it with my own version and set the environment profile?

Comment: Are you using the `-I` and `-L` options on gcc?

Comment: Are you asking how to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to change the default search order?  Note that most of boost is "header only" however, and if your program is compiling you might not need that.

Comment: I do not use the -I and -L options on GCC. Because I want to compile a opensource software. But after entering the ./bjam command, the echo tells me that my boost version is older than what it requires. So I want to compile another boost on my folder. Notice that I have no access to the /user/local folder. But after the boost is compiled, I again compile the opensource software but it looks like that it does not invoke the new boost.

Comment: Add the directory to the ldconfig path. `man ldconfig` will point you to the files you need to edit. After editing, run `ldconfig -v`

Answer (score 0):

When you are compiling your application, use the gcc arguments `-isystem /home/lixiang/local -L /home/lixiang/local` to build and link against an alternate version of boost.

If you are unable to modify the open source code, or simply do not want to, it may expose a configure script that can do this for you: .`/configure --with-boost=/home/lixiang/local` may work.